books and websites suggestion
I am looking for exercises similar to this one, which aims to prove that a Lipschitz function with
0
<

<
1
0<k<1 has a unique fixed point. Specifically, I’m interested in books or websites offering exercises with multiple parts that progressively guide the reader through proofs or concepts. Do you have any recommendations?

I=[a;b]
Let $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(I) \subset I$, and suppose that $f$ satisfies the condition:

$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k |x - y|, \quad \forall x, y \in I \text{ with } 0 < k < 1.
$$


We consider the sequence $(u_n)_n$ defined by

$$$$
\begin{cases}
u_{n+1} = f(u_n), \\
u_0 \in I.
\end{cases}
$$$$



Show that the terms of the sequence are well-defined.




Show that $| u_{n+1} - u_n | \leq k^n | u_1 - u_0 |$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 < k < 1$.




Deduce that $u_n - k^n(b - a) \leq u_{n+1} \leq u_n + k^n(b - a)$.




Let


$$
\begin{cases}
v_n = u_n + \alpha k^n(b - a), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \\
w_n = -\alpha k^n(b - a) + u_n, \quad a, b \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } a < b.
\end{cases}
$$

4-1) Show that the sequences $(v_n)_n$ and $(w_n)_n$ are adjacent if $\alpha \geq \frac{1}{1 - k}$.


4-2) Show that $(u_n)_n$ converges to $l \in [a, b]$ if $\alpha \geq \frac{1}{1 - k}$.


4-3) Let $\alpha \geq \frac{1}{1 - k}$. Verify that $k \leq \frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ (positive real numbers excluding zero).







5-1) Show that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and deduce that $f(l) = l$.


5-2) Show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $|u_n - l| \leq k |u_{n+1} - l|$.



Show that if $l_1 = f(l_1)$ and $l_2 = f(l_2)$ with $l_1, l_2 \in I$, then $l_1 = l_2$.




Show that $\forall (n, p) \in \mathbb{N}, |u_{n+p} - u_n| \leq k^n \frac{1 - k^p}{1 - k} |u_1 - u_0|$.




Deduce that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|u_n - l| \leq \frac{k^n}{1 - k} |u_1 - u_0|$.



You may like "A concise introduction to analysis" by Daniel Stroock.
